# Como iniciar numa determinada aba do tabindex (primefaces)?

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Como faço para quando exibir uma  numa determinada aba?
Eu tentei usar o `tabIndex="#{meuBean.tabIndex}"`setando para 0,1,2 e etc, mas ao abrir ele sempre se posiciona na primeira aba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
PF('suaTabView').select(1);
```

Ex:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('tabViewEdit').select(0);" />
```

Ou pode ativar a aba através de um atributo no Managed Bean

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="${meuMB.tabAtiva}" >
```

Comment: Nilson no caso eu preciso que o valor venha do bean, pois eu estou vindo de outra pagina para uma tab específica. O usuário seleciona um determinada informação numa página e ao carregar a tab (outra página) eu gostaria de abrí-la automaticamente.

Comment: Veja se o novo exemplo funciona

Comment: Fiz os ajustes e funcionou. Valeu!